# Make a function setInterval/recursive

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I've got a function here that outputs seconds as days, minutes, and seconds, and I'd like it run once a second, and add one to the delta - giving a semi accurate difference between two dates.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#time").length) {

        var delta = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;

        function timer(delta) {
            setInterval(function() {
                // calculate (and subtract) whole days
                var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
                delta -= days * 86400;
                // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
                var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
                delta -= hours * 3600;
                // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
                var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
                delta -= minutes * 60;
                // what's left is seconds
                var seconds = delta % 60; 
                // console.log(minutes);
                console.log(days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds)
                timer(delta + 1)
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
});
```

What do I need to change to achieve this? I have some familiarity with recursion - but not a lot, in all honesty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change ['setInterval'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) to ['setTimeout'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

`setInterval` according to MDN:

> Repeatedly calls a function or executes a code snippet, with a fixed
>   time delay between each call. Returns an intervalID.

Which means that it will run the once per 1000ms, and call the `timer()` function that will spawn another `setInterval`. Now you'll have to 2 `setInterval` running, 4 after 1000ms, etc...

`setTimeout` on the other hand expires after it invokes the callback. The callback will execute, and start a new timer, and the cycle will continue.

```js
var time = document.getElementById('time');

function timer(delta) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // calculate (and subtract) whole days
    var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
    delta -= days * 86400;
    // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
    var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
    delta -= hours * 3600;
    // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
    var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
    delta -= minutes * 60;
    // what's left is seconds
    var seconds = delta % 60;
    
    time.innerHTML = (days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds);
    timer(delta + 1)
  }, 1000);
}

timer(0);
```

```html
<div id="time"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can continue to use `setInterval()` if you update the outer variable `delta` within your `timer()` function

```js
var delta = document.getElementById('time').innerHTML;

  function timer() {
      // calculate (and subtract) whole days
      var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
      delta -= days * 86400;
      // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
      var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
      delta -= hours * 3600;
      // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
      var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
      delta -= minutes * 60;
      // what's left is seconds
      var seconds = delta % 60;
      // console.log(minutes);
      document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds;
      delta++;
  }

setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="time">0</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would write it out :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    function Timer(delta) {
     // Local variables
     var delta, intervalId;

     this.start = function(initialDelta) {
      if (!intervalId) {
          delta = initialDelta;
          intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
                 // calculate (and subtract) whole days
                 var days = Math.floor(delta / 86400);
                 delta -= days * 86400;
                 // calculate (and subtract) whole hours
                 var hours = Math.floor(delta / 3600) % 24;
                 delta -= hours * 3600;
                 // calculate (and subtract) whole minutes
                 var minutes = Math.floor(delta / 60) % 60;
                 delta -= minutes * 60;
                 // what's left is seconds
                 var seconds = delta % 60; 
                 // console.log(minutes);
                 console.log(days + " " + hours + " " + minutes + " " + seconds)
                 delta++;
          })
      }
     }

     this.stop = function() {
      if (intervalId) {
       window.clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
     }
    }

    if ($("#time").length) {
        var timer = new Timer();
        var delta = parseInt(document.getElementById('time').innerHTML);
        timer.start(delta);
      
        window.setTimeout(function() { timer.stop(); }, 5000);
    }
});
```

Quick explanation : by using a constructor function `Timer`, you can isolate `delta` to each instance of Timer (like a private variable of a class in Java). By doing this, you avoid having to use recursion and your initial method using setInterval works perfectly well for this purpose, because every time the function is called, it can access and modify its own local `delta`.

This would allow you to start multiple timers, start them with different delta values, etc..